# Debugging .exe file using VCEXPRESS and an existing Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, exe

I have a .EXE file which I need to debug using `VCEXPRESS` using the code in an existing Visual Studio solution (.sln). Basically I trying to do something like this:

```
VCEXPRESS.EXE program.exe -use project.sln
```

I know I can do this

```
VCEXPRESS.EXE program.exe code.cpp
```

But then I may not be able to navigate through the whole code as `VCEXPRESS` only sees code.cpp. and also the .exe file contains the code in the solution plus some extra code. Is there is a way to achieve what I am trying or anything similar to it? 
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The solution is to open the VS solution and use visual studio commands to add the .exe file as an existing project. It will be something like this

```
VCEXPRESS.EXE solution.sln /COMMAND "File.AddExistingProject program.exe"
```

You can also open a source code file like this

```
VCEXPRESS.EXE solution.sln code.cpp /COMMAND "File.AddExistingProject program.exe"
```

This will open the solution and code.cpp in the editor, then add program.exe as an existing project and allows you to debug it. 
I hope someone in the future finds this answer useful.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, please mark the helpful reply as the answer, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue to find and research this answer, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I debug it using different VS versions. One workaround I could think of is using the /DebugExe, but it doesn't work if I use the Express version since it has many limitations in command line.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274.aspx

But if I use the VS2015 community version which was also free in command line, I could debug the specified executable file. Would you please use the high VS version like the community which is also free and it has much more features than express version.

If I have misunderstood this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot switch to a different VS version I have to use 2010 express. Anyway, I solved and posted the solution. Thank you so much.